# Formatting date (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, date, format

I'm having a problem with formatting date with date() function. My code is:

```
<?
        $vysledek=mysql_query("select * from akce order by datum limit 1");

        while ($zaznam=MySQL_Fetch_Array($vysledek))
            echo 
                "<b>".$zaznam["nadpis"]."</b>"."<br />\n".
                "<i>", 

                date("j.n.Y h:i", $zaznam["datum"]), 

                "</i>"."<br />\n"."<br />\n".
                $zaznam["text"]."<br />\n"."<br />\n"."<br />\n";
?>
```

The whole data loaded from database displays correctly except the date, which returns 1.1.1970 01:33.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$zaznam["datum"]` probably isn't a timestamp which is the format the second parameter of `date()` expects. Use [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to do this:

```
 date("j.n.Y h:i", strtotime($zaznam["datum"]))
```